# Properties not displayed in Angular

Tags: angular, properties, property-binding

I'm new to Angular, trying to learning by doing.

There is something I do not understand, why don't the properties display in the following code under `.wagon-placeholder`? There is for me no difference between `{{TrackIdStyle}}` in the first div and `{{TrackId}}` in the second div. And why `[pos]` doesn't work too?

Thank you for your clarification.

(full) track.component.html

```
<div class="setRelative">
    <div class="track-id" style={{TrackIdStyle}}>{{TrackId}}</div>
    <div class="track-id track-id-2" *ngIf="TrackIsBoth">{{TrackId}}</div>
    <div class="track-line"></div>
    
    <div class="setFlex">
        <div class="placeholder" *ngFor="let place of qty_placeholder;"
             track={{TrackId}}
             [pos]="place"
             style="width:{{placewidth}}px"
             >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Returns the following:

```
<div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="setRelative">
    <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="track-id" style="right: -1.3em;">86</div>
    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->
    <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="track-line"></div>
    <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="setFlex">
        <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="placeholder" style="width: 90.7692px;"></div>
        <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="placeholder" style="width: 90.7692px;"></div>
        <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="placeholder" style="width: 90.7692px;"></div>
        <div _ngcontent-uvg-c46="" class="placeholder" style="width: 90.7692px;"></div>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,1,2,3"
        }-->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is `<div class="placeholder" style="blabla" track="blabla" pos=1></div>`

`qty_placeholder` is simply an array [1,2,3,...] *

Comment: can you update the data stored in `qty_placeholder ` ?

Comment: you should read about `ngStyle` and `ngClass` directives. 
`ngStyle` will enable you to add dynamic styles and `ngClass` will enable you to add the CSS classes

Comment: `qty_placeholder` is simply an array [1,2,3,...]

Comment: @Irshad Yes, it is in my ToDo list thank you. I wanted to understand why the properties don't show up in the second div

Comment: @Eugène -- check the answer below. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a custom attribute on an HTML element, use `[attr.attribute-name] = "value"`

Below is the modified snippet of the second div.

```
 <div class="placeholder" *ngFor="let place of qty_placeholder;"
 [attr.track] ="TrackId"
 [attr.pos]="place"
 [ngStyle]="{'width.px': placewidth}"
 >
    </div>
```

Since, The values were not provided. I have set out the property values as below:

```
 qty_placeholder = [1,2,3,4];
  TrackId = "TRACK_ID";
  placewidth = 300
```

The output:

```
<!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,2,3,4"
}-->
<div _ngcontent-yju-c37="" class="placeholder" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" 
track="TRACK_ID" pos="1" style="width: 300px;"></div>
<div _ngcontent-yju-c37="" class="placeholder" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" 
track="TRACK_ID" pos="2" style="width: 300px;"></div>
<div _ngcontent-yju-c37="" class="placeholder" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" 
track="TRACK_ID" pos="3" style="width: 300px;"></div>
<div _ngcontent-yju-c37="" class="placeholder" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" 
track="TRACK_ID" pos="4" style="width: 300px;"></div>
```